# Android Firebase : Search in Custom Listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I creating an app that has a custom listview. My problem is it not functioning properly. Look at the image below . That's my custom listview.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeMOl.jpg)

Then when i want try to search . This happen .

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd4rE.jpg)

As you can see. The text in the Edittext is not matching with the result in custom listview. But when i try to click the result in custom listview. it redirect me on the page of the edittext string. My only problem is the text result in custom listview is not matching with the text input in the edittext.

This is my codes.

ListViewAdapter.java

```
public class LstViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList> implements Filterable {

private Context context;
private int resource;
private int id;
private LstViewAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList arrayList;
private FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
private Filter filter;


public LstViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, int id, ArrayList arrayList){
    super(context, resource, id, arrayList);
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.id = id;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.adapter = this;
}

// Hold views of the ListView to improve its scrolling performance
private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView type;
    public ImageButton removeButton;

}

public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;
    // Inflate the list_item.xml file if convertView is null
    if(rowView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView= inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.type= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        viewHolder.removeButton= (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(btn_del);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }

    final String x = (String) arrayList.get(position);
    final String y = arrayList.get(position).toString().trim();
    // Set text to each TextView of ListView item
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    holder.type.setText(x);
    holder.removeButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deletes);
    holder.removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder2=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder2.setTitle("Delete Class");
            builder2.setMessage("Do you want to delete class "+y+"?");
            final EditText input = new EditText(context);
            input.setHint("hint");
            builder2.setIcon(R.drawable.deletes);
            builder2.setPositiveButton("Delete",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    arrayList.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Class " + y + " has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("teacher").child(user.getUid().toString().trim()).child("class").child(y);
                    mDatabase.setValue(null);

                }
            });

            builder2.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder2.show();

        }
    });
    return rowView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null)
        filter = new AppFilter<String>(arrayList);
    return filter;
}

private class AppFilter<T> extends Filter {

    private String sourceObjects;

    public AppFilter(String objects) {
        sourceObjects = new AppFilter<String>(arrayList);
        synchronized (this) {
            sourceObjects.addAll(objects);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence chars) {
        String filterSeq = chars.toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        if (filterSeq != null && filterSeq.length() > 0) {
            String filter = new AppFilter<String>(arrayList);

            for (T object : sourceObjects) {
                // the filtering itself:
                if (object.toString().toLowerCase().contains(filterSeq))
                    filter.add(object);
            }
            result.count = filter.size();
            result.values = filter;
        } else {
            // add all objects
            synchronized (this) {
                result.values = sourceObjects;
                result.count = sourceObjects.size();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                  FilterResults results) {
        // NOTE: this function is *always* called from the UI thread.
        String filtered = (String) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        clear();
        for (int i = 0, l = filtered.size(); i < l; i++)
            add((String) filtered.get(i));
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
}
```

}

MainActivity

```
public class MyClassesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btnCreateClass;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private ListView mUserList;
private ArrayList<String> mUsername = new ArrayList<>();
private FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
private FirebaseAuth auth;
final String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().toString().trim();
String selectedItem, value;
LstViewAdapter arrayAdapter;
private EditText inputSearch;
int textlength = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_classes);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Classes");
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    btnCreateClass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createclass);
    mUserList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userlist);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    inputSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //get current user
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    arrayAdapter= new LstViewAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem,R.id.txt, mUsername);
    mUserList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("teacher").child(user.getUid().toString().trim()).child("class");
    mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            value = dataSnapshot.getKey().toString().trim();
            mUsername.add(value);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    btnCreateClass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyClassesActivity.this, CreateClassActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mUserList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyClassesActivity.this, StudentListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("secname", selectedItem);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_class, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            // app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.
            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:

            if (id == R.id.search) {
                inputSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                inputSearch.requestFocus();
                //Do something
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

listitem.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_del"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/deletes"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Comment: please can you provide your getFilter method of Adapter class

Comment: getfilter is inside my textwatcher.

Comment: Add your Adapter class which has the getFilter method

Comment: I dont have getfilter method in my LstViewAdapter. i don't know how to use it. My LstViewAdapter above is my Adapter Class.

Comment: I think you should have a look at this https://gist.github.com/tobiasschuerg/3554252. It overrides the getFilter in Adapter class.

Comment: I'll check this . I wish that this will help me to solve my problem. Thank you for helping me. I'll update you for the results. Thank you very much

Comment: i got an error after i add some code from that link.

Comment: I updated my code above. I put a arrow where i got the error.

Comment: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.vincedamsel.firebase, PID: 19779
                                                   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
                                                       at com.example.vincedamsel.firebase.LstViewAdapter$AppFilter.publishResults(LstViewAdapter.java:170)`

Comment: your filter = new AppFilter<ArrayList>(arrayList); should be of type String filter = new AppFilter<String>(arrayList); and the statement where you fetch it in publish results cast it to String and not ArrayList

Comment: I'll try it later. Thank you again.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/HByNe